# Reading cells from an Existing Excel File and Writing them into a new Excel File using Java

Tags: java, excel, jxl

So I'm currently creating a program to read, edit and place data from an existing Excel file into a new Excel File using the JXL Java library. At this stage I will just like to read data from the existing Excel file and place it into the new one. Can't seem to find a good way of doing it and for future work what is the best way to edit the data (having certain columns) and placing them into the new Excel File.

Sorry if anything is unclear, just getting grips with Java and Stackoverflow.

```
import java.io.*;
import jxl.*;
import jxl.write.Number;
import jxl.write.*;

class Extraction {

private String inputFile;

String data;

public void setInputFile(String inputFile){

    this.inputFile = inputFile;

}

public void read() throws IOException {

    File spreadsheet = new File(inputFile);

    Workbook w;

    try {

        w = Workbook.getWorkbook(spreadsheet);

        Sheet page = w.getSheet(0);

        File f = new File("C:\\Users\\alex\\Desktop\\New_Export.xls");                                                                                      

            if (!f.exists()){

                String FileName = "C:\\Users\\alex\\Desktop\\New_Export.xls";

                WritableWorkbook excel = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(FileName));

                WritableSheet sheet = excel.createSheet("Sheet1", 0);                                           

                    for (int y = 0; y < page.getRows(); y++){

                        for (int x = 0; x < page.getColumns(); x++){

                            Cell cell = page.getCell(x ,y +1);
                            CellType type = cell.getType();

                                if(type == CellType.LABEL || type == CellType.NUMBER){

                                    data = cell.getContents();

                                    System.out.println(data);




                                    //To now input the read data into the new Excel File

                                    sheet.addCell();

                                }

                        }

                        System.out.println(" ");

                    }   

                System.out.println("The File Has Successfully Been Created!");

                excel.write();

                excel.close();

                }

                else{

                    System.err.println("File is already created!");

                }

    }
    catch(Exception e){

        System.out.println(" ");  

    }       

}       

public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException{

    Extraction reading = new Extraction();

    reading.setInputFile("C:\\Users\\alex\\Desktop\\export.xls"); 

    reading.read();

}
}
```

Comment: any special reason for using jxl over apache poi?

Comment: No particular reason. Would Apache POI be more capable/flexible for this task?

Comment: I think that you can complete your task with both libraries, but as i see it jxl got its last update in 2012 (so possibly dead) and POI in 2015. On top of that, you have some noname library versus an apache product (which only a few might know, but its still under the hood of apache). You should always use/learn something what has the better future and support, if you have the choice.

Comment: After hear some more information on POI, I may swap over to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the "poi" from apache, you can use the below code to read the excel (*.xls)

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

private void readingExcel(String fileName) {
    try (FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName))) {
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
        for (Row row : sheet) {
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            for (Cell cell : row) {
                System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

For writing to excel

```
private File writingToExcel() {
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sample-sheet");
    Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
    Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
    cell.setCellValue("My Sample Value");

    File file = new File(sheet.getSheetName());
    return file;
}
```

However, if you want to use *.xlsx, the class used to read is

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook (file); 
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
```

Comment: Would this work by passing the data from the reading the excel through to writing it to the new one?